# Making a simple tamagoci game getting no compiler errors but receiving no output

Tags: actionscript-3

Kind of new Actionscript and I'm just trying to make a simple tamagoci game. I've wrote all the code out but and receiving no compiler errors but for some reason I'm also not receiving any output messages for my mouse event listeners. Here is all my code, I really can't find the problem and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
package{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    public var feedButton:MovieClip;
    public var tamagoci:MovieClip; 
    public var disButton:MovieClip;
    public var dietButton:MovieClip;

    public function Main() {
        this.init();
    }

    private function init():void {

        this.feedButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onfeedMouseDownHandler); 
        this.disButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ondisMouseDownHandler); 
        this.dietButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ondietMouseDownHandler); 


    }

    private function onfeedMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent)void{
        this.tamagoci.scaleX += 0.1;
        this.tamagoci.scaleY += 0.1;
    }

    private function ondisMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent)void{
        this.tamagoci.gotoAndPlay(5);
}
private function ondietMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent)void{
        this.tamagoci.scaleX -= 0.1;
        this.tamagoci.scaleY -= 0.1;
```

}

Comment: You're not outputting any messages in the code above.

Comment: Use trace statements to check your code.  For example, put this as first line in your onfeedMouseDownHandler() function to see when function is called in your output window:  trace("onfeedMouseDownHandler()");

Comment: I've submitted a possible answer, but I've had to speculate on how your project has been set up. If you can expand your question further, like whether you've created any other classes, written any other code, or created MovieClips in your library, this will help to identify the problem. Provide as much information about how you've set up your project as you can, or even better, a copy of your project including the .fla file and any .as files you've created.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flash Professional?

You're declaring your variable types in your class here;

```
public var feedButton:MovieClip;
public var tamagoci:MovieClip; 
public var disButton:MovieClip;
public var dietButton:MovieClip;
```

But then in your constructor, all you are doing is running `init();`

```
public function Main() {
        this.init();
    }
```

So, this could one of a few things. The most likely is that you have declared your variables, but you haven't initialised them. You've created the variables to hold your objects, but according to your code, they're empty. More specifically, a variable or class property that doesn't assign an object to a variable of an object type will contain a default value of `null`.

You could prove this in your code by simply putting a condition inside your `init();` method;

```
if(tamagoci == null){
    trace("I haven't been assigned an object of type class yet!")
}
```

So it could be 1 of these 3 things:

**1:** If you have written your own classes for these class properties/variables, then you need to instantiate them with the `new` keyword. The general syntax is;

```
variable_name = new ClassName(parameter_1, parameter_2);
```

If you are using classes you have written yourself, you have to create an instance of the object, assign it to a variable, and then add it to the stage using `addChild();`. For example, lets say you've written your own `Tamagoci` class;

tamagoci = new Tamagoci();
tamagoci.x = 100; // set the x location
tamagoci.y = 200; // set the y location
addChild(tamagoci);

Notice the use of `Tamagoci`. This is just an example, but this is the *class name*, which shouldn't be confused with variable/property name. It could just have easily been;

```
tamagoci = new MovieClip();
```

But then, this is just an empty MovieClip. It needs a property to display on the screen. A `Shape`, A `Bitmap`, or another container class object like `MovieClip` or `Sprite` (container classes allow you to nest display objects inside them). But on a basic level, it *must* contain a visual component to appear on the stage.

**2:**

Have you made `Main` your document class? This is the class which will get automatically called when your Flash movie plays. To set this, click on your stage, and in the properties dialogue box on the right, under **PUBLISH**, type in the name of your class, which is "Main".

**3:**

If you have created MovieClips in your library in Flash Professional, then you need to go to your library, right click the MovieClips, and select *properties*. From there, you need to make sure *Export for Actionscript* is ticked.

Now, if you click on your MovieClips on the stage, then open the Properties tab in the top right of Flash Professional's default layout, then right at the top should be a text field, and if you hover over it, *Instance name* will pop up as a tool tip. This is where you name your stage objects. Once that is done, you have access to them in your timeline.

If this is how you've done this, then you don't need to declare the variables in your `main` class, as they are already declared on your stage by Flash Professional and instantiated automatically.